# Magento: Custom file upload from product edit page

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, file-upload

i have created a custom tab inside the product page (backend) and need to be able to upload a file from there.

Here is my code:

> Vendor/Module/UI/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Attachements.php

```
....

protected function getDataUploadField()
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'componentType' => 'fileUploader',
                    'formElement' => 'fileUploader',
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/file-uploader',
                    'dataScope' => 'file',
                    'fileInputName' => 'image',
                    'uploaderConfig' => [
                        'url' => $this->urlBuilder->addSessionParam()->getUrl(
                            'adminhtml/attachements_file/upload'
                        ),
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ];
}

....
```

> Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Attachements\File.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Attachements;

abstract class File extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Magento_Catalog::products';
}
```

> Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Attachements\File\Upload.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Attachements\File;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Upload extends \Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Attachements\File
{
    protected $UploaderFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $UploaderFactory,
        Action\Context $context

    ) {

        $this->UploaderFactory = $UploaderFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute(){

        $uploader = $this->UploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']); //ERROR

        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);

        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

        $path = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)
        ->getAbsolutePath('images/');

        $uploader->save($path);

    }
}
```

But I always get:

> File was not uploaded.

I even tried to change the error message in Magento/Framework/File/Uploader.php to

`throw new \Exception('File was not uploaded. ' . $this->_file['error'], $code)`

But `$this->_file['error']` is always empty.

Comment: you got solution ?

Comment: No, sorry. Never got this working.

Comment: you still need that or not ? @TrytoFly

Comment: Yes, we decided to cut the uploader out of the project until we find a proper way to implement it.

Comment: Okay I have solution :). if you ever decided to do that let me know.

Comment: hey @ephemeral I need help for this issue? can you help

Comment: @MandarParbate  you got solution or still stuck ?

Comment: We have resolve it by calling custom template on product edit page.

Comment: @ephemeral you have any other solutions??

Comment: you got solution ?